# how to make my Google Cloud functions not deployed when performing testing?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

say for example in my `index.ts` I have this code below

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.firestore.document('/messages/{documentId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

});

exports.clearOtherDocs = functions.firestore.document('/messages/{documentId}')
    .onDelete((snap, context) => {

});

// actually I have more than 15 functions like that located in some files (not only in index.ts )
```

currently I am testing my cloud functions using Mocha / Jest. and if those functions is deployed (locally using emulator), then those Firestore triggers will ruin my tests.

so how to make those Firestore triggers will not be deployed locally when I am performing testing using Mocha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I find the solution.

before running the testing, instead of run all emulators using

```
firebase emulators:start
```

I need to just run the emulator needed. in my case, I only need firestore and authentication emulators, so I run this code below before run the script testing

```
firebase emulators:start --only firestore,auth
```

Comment: Did this solve your problem? If so, please accept your answer in order to increase visibility